# JS - Compare which date is older

Tags: javascript

I want to compare two dates as which is bigger in those dates.

```
var date1 = 2011-9-2;
var date1 = 2011-17-06;
```

Can anybody say how can I do this?

Comment: How can this possibly be tagged "Java"?

Comment: If you want to compare two date in javascript this post may help [Stakoverflow old thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752532/javascript-date-comparison)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281937/check-the-dates-in-javascript

Comment: @Sateesh You might want to edit your question. `var date1 = 2011-9-2;` means compute 2011 minue 9 minus 2 and initialize the new variable `date1` to this value, which is 2000.  Also accept one of the answers below.  This question is over a week old.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to convert both strings to date objects first.

```
var date1 = new Date('2011-09-02');//yyyy-mm-dd format
var date2 = new Date('2011-06-17');
if(date1 > date2){
  alert('date1 is bigger than date2'); 
}
```

Once you have the 2 variables as date objects you can compare them against each other (without needing to convert to milliseconds/minutes/?)

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javadate.html)

And then do something like this:

```
var days = 0;
var difference = 0;
Christmas = new Date("December 25, 2005");
today = new Date();
difference = Christmas - today;
days = Math.round(difference/(1000*60*60*24));
```

[Code source](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/javascript-date-comparison-t46552.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create Date objects from your two values (check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) link) and use that to do the comparison.